# How can I stop Hootsuite from trying to send this failing message?

Tags: twitter

So I try to send a tweet from hootsuite about this really nice beer I had. It was a nice beer, and a nice tweet, and nothing weird about it at the time.

The message send failed -- see screenshot, below.

The message cannot be found in hootsuite --  the message doesn't appear in my twitter feed, nor in "sent messages" (of course) -- the "Pending" tab is empty.

The message send KEEPS failing -- even though I've posted other messages from Hootsuite to Twitter since then. The message keeps trying to resend (and fail) every few minutes [no idea of actual frequency, but if I dismiss the message, it reappears sooner or later].

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the data for the app?  Or uninstalling then reinstalling?  Or does Hootsuite cache unsent/failed tweets to the cloud?

Comment: I'm reluctant to uninstall, because I don't want to have to reconnect the three accounts. But if that's the only option.... [and "clearing data" clears all account data too, right?]

Comment: Yeah, clearing data will be like starting the app anew.

Comment: "clearing data" made me think some more... what could be done to reset?, without being destructive? REBOOT! Once restarted, the offending message was FINALLY visible in the pending messages. I deleted it. Thanks!